# class.getResourceAsStream gives back null in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I'm trying to create an app in Android Studio that can access a [Google Sheets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Sheets) sheet. My *credentials.json* file is like this:

```
{"client_id":[My ID], "project_id":"androidandsheets", "auth_uri":[My auth URI], "token_uri":[My token URI], "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":[URL]}
```

But when I use this Java code,

```
private Credential authorize() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException{
    InputStream in = SheetsAndJava.class.getResourceAsStream("credentials.json");
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(
            GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),new InputStreamReader(in)
    );
    List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);

    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
            GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
            clientSecrets,scopes
            ).setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new File("tokens")))
            .setAccessType("offline").build();

    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
            flow,new LocalServerReceiver()
    ).authorize("user");

    return credential;
}
```

the input stream returned by *InputStream in = SheetsAndJava.class.getResourceAsStream("credentials.json")* is null.

How can I fix this issue?

Here's my layout for this project. For some reason, the *credentials.json* file is visible in the project view, but not in the Android view.

[image: Android View]

[image: Project View]

Comment: Can you show the directory structure of your project? The `credentials.json` needs to be in the same package (but in a resource folder) as your `SheetsAndJava` class.

Comment: @dan1st i just added both android view and project view of my project

Answer (score 0):

`Class#getResource` and `Class#getResourceAsStream` looks for the resource relative to the class/in the same package. This leaves you with multiple options:

### Move `credentials.json`

Since it is looking for the `credentials.json` file in `com/example/excelintro`, the problem should be solved by just moving it to `res/com/example/excelintro`.

### Use `ClassLoader#getResource`/`ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream`

Instead of calling `SheetsAndJava.class.getResourceAsStream(...)` (or `SheetsAndJava.class.getResource(...)`) (which resolves the resource relative to the class), you can use `SheetsAndJava.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(...)` (or `SheetsAndJava.class.getClassLoader().getResource(...)`). This resolves the resource relative to the classpath root (the `res` folder).

#### Append a leading `/` to the resource name

If you use `/credentials.json` instead of just `credentials.json`, it should also resolve the resource from the classpath root.

Comment: What do you mean by res/com/example/excelintro i dont think i have a folder of this pathname

Comment: You would need to create a folder `excelintro` in a folder `example` in a folder `com` in the `res` folder and put the `credentials.json` into that (`excelintro`) folder.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but this worked thank you @dan1st